# unbound class path container error in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I tried to import my project into ecclipse, but im get following error Description
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [jre1.5.0_16]' in project 'myproject', 
 How i can resolve this error

Answer (score 61, accepted):

An unbounded classpath container for an Eclipse project implies that the JRE associated with the project is not available in the list of JREs available in the workspace. You will need to modify your Java build path (accessible via Project Preferences), to use a JRE definition that is valid in your workspace.

[image: Eclipse - Edit JRE System Library]

You can choose your workspace default JRE or an alternate JRE, or even a JRE that matches an execution environment (like Java 5 or Java 6).

[image: Eclipse - JRE specification]

**Edit**: As an alternative, you can add the missing JRE to your workspace.  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm

Comment: thanx, now i'm getting error like this Description 
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. myproject  Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)

Comment: Check your Java project facet in the "Project Facets" page of project preferences, and Java compiler level in the "Java" compiler page; both of them should match. It is likely that you have created a Java project with facet 5.0 and compiler level 1.6, or you are using an incompatible JDK/JRE in your Java build path. Also, if you are getting different errors, please post them in different questions on StackOverflow (after having researched them first).