# how to set specific system JRE due to Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I imported Java project from SVN and want to run it without changing the classpath. I installed JDK 8 (java -version shows

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

), but on the project I see error:

> Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project

I also added "Standard VM" in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installer JREs, but it didn't help.
I guess I have to set my system JRE exactly to JRE which is set in the project. But as far as I understand, it's the save version...

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6798326/5588347)

Comment: @AshishSrivastava it changes the classpath, which I wrote not want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments'.

Click on 'JavaSE-1.8' and select the JRE to be used.

Comment: Thanks. But what to do if I don't have 'JavaSE-1.8' there?

Comment: As long as you are using recent releases of Eclipse it will be there. If you don't have it your Eclipse release is too old for Java 8.

Comment: It's very weird. We use software which is based on Eclipse Juno. Project is created by colleague which has the same version as me, and still there is Java 1.8 on the project classpath.

Comment: It is actually possible to add new Execution Environment definitions (see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm)) maybe your colleague did that.

Comment: Finally, I was wrong. This mate has another version of software. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can provide project specific JDK/JRE by right clicking on project and then select configure properties. There you can update java compiler.

Comment: What you mean by "configure properties"?

Comment: It means, right click on the project and select the properties option available in the end. Then a popup will appear from where you can select Java compiler and can check what is actually present in your project.

Comment: OK, i see. But it's weird for me (probably this cause the problem) - I don't have 1.8 there...

Answer (score 0):

You can select it on run configuration. Then, click on your run option, and then select JRE overlap.

this example is for eclipse 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for screen, but can you explain how I can go there?

Comment: On top you have run image, and here you can click run configuration. Then choose your application profile and next is on screen

Comment: Whatever I choose, I have warning "Execution environment not compatible with project .class file compatibility: 1.8" :(